# Will lastest websphere liberty full platform run oracle java 8?

Tags: java-8, websphere-liberty, ibm-jdk, oraclejdk

I am looking at the latest websphere liberty 8.5.5.7 full platform (https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/) and I wonder if it can run oracle java 8? I see on the download page that ibms java 8 only supports the web profile but I don't care if i run a jdk from oracle or ibm as long as it is version 8.

Historically websphere has demanded ibms jdk on linux and solaris.

I have search ibms site but not found any answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes we support running Liberty on non-IBM JVMs, including those from Oracle. As for the downloads from IBM that come bundled with Java 8 you can use that with more than the web profile (you can use the installUtility to download and install the full Java EE 7 platform onto the web profile install).

Comment: You might also include a link to the "Minimum supported Java levels" section of the "Liberty profile: Runtime environment known issues and restrictions" topic in the Knowledge Center, which has the same authoritative answer: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_restrict.html

Comment: (Interestingly, that section starts "any compliant Java™ SE 6 or Java SE 7 runtime environment" but then goes on to list "Java SE 8 runtime environment".)

Comment: Thanks @thomas Banks. So I understand that I can run ibm jdk 8 with the full profile if I download the web profile first and then update it?

Comment: That confused me to @bkail.

Comment: @user1329339 With the Java EE 7 full platform on WAS Liberty yes. Once you have installed the web profile you can run "wlp/bin/installUtility install javaee-7.0" which should install the Java EE 7 full platform capabilities into the Liberty runtime for you.